# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'div'

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to run following program of using python 3.2 , there is error: 'module' object has no attribute 'div' Can anybody tell me what should I do to fix this? i really appreciate it !

```
import operator 
ops = {'+':operator.add,'-':operator.sub,'*':operator.mul,'/':operator.div}
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'div

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), there is a truediv and a floordiv in Python 3. You need to use one of these.

> operator.truediv(a, b) operator.__truediv__(a, b) Return a / b where
>   2/3 is .66 rather than 0. This is also known as “true” division.
>
> operator.floordiv(a, b) operator.__floordiv__(a, b) Return a // b

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3 `operator` module you need to use either `truediv` or `floordiv`. [See the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) on mapping mapping operators to functions in the operator module.